# Using aws-s3-v3 with laravel and digitalocean spaces results in error 501 not implemented

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, flysystem

I am trying to upload some files to a `s3` compatible storage from digitalocean (spaces) using `Laravel 8` and `flysystem-aws-s3-v3`.

But when I submit those files I'm getting this error:

```
Aws\S3\Exception\S3Exception
Error executing "PutObject" on "//SPACES_NAME.nyc3.digitaloceanspaces.com/SPACES_NAME.nyc3.digitaloceanspaces.com"; AWS HTTP error: Server error: `PUT http://SPACES_NAME.nyc3.digitaloceanspaces.com/SPACES_NAME.nyc3.digitaloceanspaces.com` resulted in a `501 Not Implemented` response: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Error><Code>NotImplemented</Code><RequestId>tx00000000000000bf40fd9-00605636a9-96 (truncated...) NotImplemented (server): - <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Error><Code>NotImplemented</Code><RequestId>tx00000000000000bf40fd9-0060
```

5636a9-9617be5-nyc3c9617be5-nyc3c-nyc3-zg03

Here are my digitalocean constants from `.env`:

```
DO_SPACES_ACCESS_KEY=[edit]
DO_SPACES_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=[edit]
DO_SPACES_ENDPOINT=nyc3.digitaloceanspaces.com
DO_SPACES_REGION=nyc3
DO_SPACES_BUCKET=SPACES_NAME
DO_URL=https://SPACES_NAME.nyc3.cdn.digitaloceanspaces.com
```

And here is the config part from `config/filesystem.php`:

```
'disks' => [
    ...
    'do' => [
        'driver'    => 's3',
        'key'       => env('DO_SPACES_ACCESS_KEY'),
        'secret'    => env('DO_SPACES_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
        'region'    => env('DO_SPACES_REGION'),
        'bucket'    => env('DO_SPACES_BUCKET'),
        'endpoint'  => env('DO_SPACES_ENDPOINT'),
        'url'   => env('DO_URL'),
    ],
],
```

And this is the test method that I'm using to process uploads:

```
Route::post('upload', function(){
        $extension = request()->file('file')->extension();
        $path = Storage::disk('do')->putFileAs('upload', request()->file('file'), time() . '.' .$extension, 'public');
});
```

Any thoughts on how this `501 not implemented` error could be fixed? I see that the url for some reason appears twice and I think that that has something to do with it :-?

Comment: I think it's because : DigitalOcean Spaces don’t support unencrypted transfer, so you must use HTTPS [ref](https://www.digitalocean.com/docs/spaces/resources/s3cmd/). And in the error message you can see `PUT http://SPACES_NAME.nyc3.dig...`. Try declaring the protocol on the `endpoint` key `DO_SPACES_ENDPOINT=https://nyc3.digitaloceanspaces.com`. (remenber to clear cache after change .env file values)

Comment: Ok, I tried to add `https` in front of the endpoint but then the error is saying that `SPACES_NAME.https:// protocol does not exist`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved the same problem as follows:

1. Add the following endpoint to the `.env` file

```
    DO_SPACES_ENDPOINT=https://SPACES_NAME.nyc3.digitaloceanspaces.com
```

2. Add an option in the `config/filesystem.php` file to your DO Space.

```
    'bucket_endpoint' => true
```

3. Clear the cache.

Comment: Apparently it was a `guzzlehttp/guzzle` problem. Once i downgraded `guzzlehttp/guzzle` to `7.2.0` and `aws/aws-sdk-php` to `3.174.0` it worked. But your solution also works :D

Comment: @yurii-s wich value should receive DO_SPACES_ENDPOINT?  What the key value?`'some_key_here' =>env('DO_SPACES_ENDPOINT')`